# Ant-Contrib Equals Ignore Case

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Is there a way to check if two values equal each other regardless of case?  For instance "myValue" equals "myvalue" case-insensative.

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="myValue" arg2="myvalue" />
    <then>
        ...
    </then>
</if>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ant-contrib sucks.  It usually results in spaghetti code that is really really hard to read - and requires people to add the ant-contrib jars.
You're usually better off letting ant be ant... It isn't a scripting language, but a simple declaration of build steps.  If you want to get fancy, you'd do this by writing your own task in java where you'd have an IDE, debugger and unit tests.

In ant you'd do this with the `<condition>` task, specifically `<equals>` with `casesensitive="false"` to set a property and then conditionally run a target based on that property. For example, run this guy with `ant -Darg1="foo" -Darg2="foo"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="condition" default="condition-true" basedir=".">

<condition property="strings-match">
    <equals arg1="${arg1}" arg2="${arg2}" casesensitive="false"/>
</condition>

<target name="display-props">
    <echo>"arg1 = ${arg1}"</echo>
    <echo>"arg2 = ${arg2}"</echo>
    <echo>"strings-match = ${strings-match}"</echo>
</target>

<target name="condition-true" depends="display-props" if="${strings-match}">
    <echo>true</echo>
</target>
</project>
```

I know this doesn't answer your question, which is specifically about ant-contrib. I'll even further go astray by saying I'd never make a new ant file (prefering gradle or maven) Interesting reading:

- [musings from ant's inventer](http://web.archive.org/web/20040602210721/x180.net/Articles/Java/AntAndXML.html)
- [elements of ant style](http://wiki.apache.org/ant/TheElementsOfAntStyle) (not maintained)

Comment: After further research the equals is not part of Ant-Contrib and is part of Ant Condition Task like you mentioned.  So even though I was using the <if> tag of Ant-Contrib the <equals> is part of Ant.  Further documentation points that by default casesensitive (Perform a case sensitive comparision.) Default is true.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `casesensitive="false"` parameter like this:

```
<if>
    <equals arg1="myValue" arg2="myvalue" casesensitive="false" />
    <then>
        ...
    </then>
</if>
```

Source: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html

Answer (score 0):

I bet you can use the `<matches>` condition to do this. The `<matches>` condition can compare a string against a regular expression, and can be case insensitive. Simply make the string you're matching the regular expression.

Just off the top of my head:

```
<property name="arg1" value="MY_VALUE"/>
<property name="arg2" value="my_value"/>
<if>
    <matches
        string="${arg1}"
        pattern="^${arg2}$"
        casesensitive="false">
    <then>
          <echo>${arg1} and ${arg2} are the same, but may differ in case</echo>
    </then>
</if>
```

Comment: Good use of matches, although `<equals>` does the job too.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that you can do this within the `<if>`. However, you could add a small javascript.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
  <![CDATA[
  // getting value for myValue
  myValue = test.getProperty("myValue");  
  // TODO add some check here to handle empty property value
  // convert to uppercase 
  valueUpper = myValue.toUpperCase();  
  // store the result in a new property 
  test.setProperty("myValue.upper",valueUpper); 
   ]]> 
</script>

<if>
    <equals arg1="${myValue.upper}" arg2="MYVALUE" />
    <then>
        ...
    </then>
</if>
```

*note*: `test` references your ant project name.

Alternatively you could look for another ant-contrib function `propertyRegex`. Since I didn't find a working example how to utilize it to transform a string to upper or lower case I'd consider the javascript as better choice.